# i tried to assign a value if the cell value in excel is null by using if statement in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

hi i tried to get the values from excel using apache poi and in this process if the cell value is null i assign the value and all this process is checking by using IF Statement but my code is not entering in to if Statement. can anybody please help me in this

///Code///

```
 public static String[] ParamterData(int ParameterCount,int RowNum){
    String[] data=new String[ParameterCount];
    int cell=4;
    for(int i=0;i<ParameterCount;i++){

        XSSFCell parameter=TestData.sheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(cell);
        System.out.println(parameter);
        if(parameter.getStringCellValue().equals(null)){    
            System.out.println("entered in to if loop");
            parameter.setCellValue(" ");
            File file=new File("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Test Doc and Resumes\\Testdata.xlsx");
            FileOutputStream fout;
            try {
                fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    TestData.book.write(fout);
                    parameter=TestData.sheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(cell);
                    System.out.println(parameter+ " inside if");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            data[i]=parameter.getStringCellValue(); 
        }else
        {
            data[i]=parameter.getStringCellValue();

        }
    cell=cell+1;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by IF-Loop

Comment: `if` statements are not loops.

Comment: sorry i mean if statement

Comment: What `System.out.println(parameter);` prints out?

Comment: it prints the cell values.. i used that to know whether cell has empty string or null value.. if it is null value if statement will run

Comment: why are you using 2 `\\\` in the path for your Textfile?

Comment: "it prints the cell values.": No it prints [XSSFCell.toString()](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.java?view=markup#l1031). So what exactly does it print for null values? If it prints "null", then the object `parameter` must be `null`. But then `parameter.getStringCellValue()` should throw a NPE.

Comment: richetr, so what i have to do now..